# Count number of ID in a table and select one or all top values(max) in POSTGRESQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table(film_actor) that holds a relationship between two other tables, film and actor.

I want to count the number of occurences of actor.id in the table film_actor and then select the top value or values, but cant seem to get it to work.

My query so far is as below which gives me a nice list of all actors and the number of movies they have been in. What I cant seem to do is select the highest value or values. I know I can just limit the results to 1, or top 1, but I need it to be dynamic in case the list has 2 or more actors with the same number of movies.

```
SELECT actor.first_name, actor.last_name, COUNT(actor.actor_id) AS film_number
FROM actor 
INNER JOIN film_actor ON actor.actor_id = film_actor.actor_id
GROUP BY actor.actor_id, actor.first_name, actor.last_name
ORDER BY film_number DESC
```

I havent been able to nest MAX() into this, but Im thinking this is what I need. All tips are welcome!

Comment: How would this help me select the max values? :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this by using HAVING and ALL, see below:

```
SELECT
actor.first_name, actor.last_name, COUNT(film_actor.actor_id) as Antalfilmer
FROM 
film_actor
INNER JOIN actor ON film_actor.actor_id = actor.actor_id
GROUP BY actor.first_name, actor.last_name, actor.actor_id
HAVING COUNT(film_actor.actor_id) >= ALL (SELECT COUNT(film_actor.actor_id) FROM film_actor JOIN actor ON actor.actor_id = film_actor.actor_id GROUP BY actor.first_name, actor.last_name, actor.actor_id)
```

Comment: Most times you can replace window functions with more complicated queries using subselects, having and so on. 
Window functions are more elegant but really not "entry level".

Answer (score 0):

The best way to write this type of query is to use `rank()` or `dense_rank()`:

```
SELECT fa.*
FROM (SELECT a.first_name, a.last_name, COUNT(a.actor_id) AS film_number,
             RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(a.actor_id) DESC) as seqnum
      FROM actor a INNER JOIN
           film_actor fa
           ON a.actor_id = fa.actor_id
      GROUP BY a.actor_id, a.first_name, a.last_name
     ) fa
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! This works really nice. Although I havent read anything about rank or dense-rank in the litterature thus far. Would you say this is entry level knowledge?

Comment: @klasmack . . . I would say that window/analytic functions are very important for using SQL effectively.

Comment: I've done some more research and I think I should be able to solve it with a HAVING and ALL statement, something like below.



SELECT actor.first_name, actor.last_name, COUNT(actor.actor_id) AS antal_filmer
FROM actor 
INNER JOIN film_actor ON actor.actor_id = film_actor.actor_id
HAVING COUNT(actor.actor_id) > ALL MAX()
GROUP BY actor.actor_id, actor.first_name, actor.last_name
ORDER BY antal_filmer DESC


Could this be a solution?